# What does $\sigma(X^*,(X^*,wk^*)^*)$ stand for?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

I saw a theorem online and it is:

Let $X$ be a TVS and let $x\in X$. Then $\hat{x}\in(X^*,wk^*)^*$. Therefore, we have
\begin{align*}
\sigma(X^*,X)\subseteq\sigma(X^*, (X^*, wk^*)^*).
\end{align*}
Furthermore, if $X$ is a normed space, then
\begin{align*}
\sigma(X^*,(X^*, wk^*)^*)\subseteq\sigma(X^*, X^{**}),
\end{align*}
where $X^{**}$ is the second Banach dual of the normed space $X$.

And I know $\sigma(X^*, X^{**})$ stands for weak topology on $X^*$. But what $\sigma(X^*,(X^*, wk^*)^*)$ means here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For a TVS $Y$, and any subset $F\subset Y^*$ in its topological dual, the topology $\sigma(Y,F)$ is defined as the [initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) on $X$ with respect to the family $(f\colon Y\rightarrow \mathbb{C})_{f\in F}$.

Thus in order to make sense of $\sigma(X^*,(X^*,wk^*)^*)$, put $Y=X^*$ and try to view $(X^*,wk^*)^*$ as a subspace $F\subset Y^*$. Note that $X^*\hookrightarrow (X^*,wk^*)$ is continuous, thus dualizing gives a continuous injection $(X^*,wk^*)^*\hookrightarrow X^{**}=Y^*$. Define $F$ to be the image of this injection.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. $wk^*$ seems to be an acronym. For what?

Comment: Oh, I thought this was clear, sorry. $wk^*=\sigma(X^*,X)$ is the weak-*-topology, where $X$ is identified with the subset $\{f\in X^{**}\vert \exists x\in X, \forall y\in X^*: f(y)=y(x)\}$

Comment: @jabo So what kind of topology is $\sigma(X^*,(X^*,wk^*)^*)$ on $X^*$? Thank you!